# How to calculate $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{\alpha},\alpha\in N^{+}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Now, we have the expression $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{\alpha},\alpha\in N^{+}$

1. For $\alpha=1$, we have $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(n+1\right)\cdot n=\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}$.
2. For $\alpha=2$, I just know the answer that $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{2}=\frac{n\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}{6}$, but do not konw how to prove it.
3. For $\alpha=3$, I jsut know $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{3}=\left(1+2+3+\cdots + n \right)^{2}=\left(\frac{n\left(n+1\right)}{2}\right)^{2}=\frac{n^{2}\left(n+1\right)^{2}}{4}$, but I don't konw why $\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^{3}=\left(1+2+3+\cdots + n \right)^{2}$.

So I just want to know how to prove 2 and 3.

Thank you.

Comment: Both can be proved very directly by induction.

Comment: @T.Bongers does the OP want to prove the formula is true I.e induction or derive the formula?

Comment: @Chinny84 I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @T.Bongers modified my comment.

Comment: @Chinny84 The last line of the question just says 'prove.' These are very standard induction proofs to consider. For a more general approach, see e.g. [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Comment: @T.Bongers I know that by using induction we can easily arrive the conclusion, but I just want to know if I don't know the answer, how could I find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can prove the formula by induction.

To deduce the formula, you may think the sum as a polynomial in terms $n^\alpha$, like this:

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2 = A n^3 + B n^2 + C n + D
$$

Put $n$ for $0,1,2,3$ to obtain several result:

$$
\begin{align}
    0 &= D & \mbox{ for } n=0
\\ 1 &= A+B+C+D & \mbox{ for } n=1
\\ 5 &= 8A+4B+2C+D & \mbox{ for } n=2
\\ 14 &= 27A+9B+3C+D & \mbox{ for } n=3
\end{align}
$$

Solve the above linear equations and you got $\displaystyle A=\frac{1}{3}, B=\frac{1}{2}, C=\frac{1}{6}, D=0$, which means

$$
\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{1}{3} n^3 + \frac{1}{2} n^2 + \frac{1}{6} n = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}
$$

Generalizing the idea of this you can deduce all the formula for $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n i^\alpha, \alpha \in \mathbb{N}$

In fact, it is the basic idea behind to deduce [Faulhaber's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula).

Comment: I have already been familiar with the way you give, but could you prove it in a more delicate way, thank you.

Comment: If we do not use induction to prove our guess. I think the remaining problem is to show that $f(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^\alpha$ must be a polynomial in $n$. Suppose not, there would be a $M \in \mathbb{N}$ s.t. by following the method in this answer (comparing the coefficients by puting $n=0,1,...,M+1$) will yield a linear system that is not solvable. However, the matrix $M$ deduced by the system is an square [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) with distinct $\{1,2,...,n\}$ and is invertible. Contradiction.

Comment: Once I attended a lesson given by a professor, he said the way to  solve the problem when $\alpha=2,3$ is familiar with the one when $\alpha=1$ by reversing the sequence and adding all the number up.

Comment: I don't think you can do it in "Gauss's childhood way" for $\alpha > 1$ (characteristic 0). If you really want to sum it directly, you may try to approximate the sum by integration $\int x^\alpha dx$ and you will come up with Euler-Maclaurin formula and then Bernoulli number appears again.